# ASP.NET MVC - Upload a file with SignalR

Tags: asp.net, signalr

I want to upload a file from the client to the server. Is there a way to upload a file with SignalR or must i need a  Controller for this?

Comment: Why would you use SignalR for this rather than just an HttpPost to a controller?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

SignalR is for real time messaging not uploading files.

Comment: Assume I wanted to build a stream which could be passed to a component on the server-side that required the ability to seek in a large file, where the client is a browser which has the JS File API. What would I use to implement that in a semi-performant fashion?

Comment: A streaming post to a webapi endpoint would work just fine for that. In fact, it could during processing even trigger push events regarding server side processing status in realtime if it notified your hub to push to the client while inspecting the stream.

Comment: What can we do if we want send a file with the message using SignalR not web api?

Answer (score 13):

While SignalR cannot help with the actual upload, [it can be used for updating the client with progress while a file is uploaded](https://github.com/appsoftware/aspnet-signalr-upload-progress-bar).

Comment: Apologies, link broke when an old blog was taken offline. I've copied the article and source code to [a GitHub repo](https://github.com/appsoftware/aspnet-signalr-upload-progress-bar). Should stay there this time :)

Comment: Its just sleeping, not actually stream handling

Answer (score 3):

This file uploading using file input bootstrap plugin (krajee)
You can also upload file without using this plugin.

```
    @section Page{

    <script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap-switch.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/Uploader/fileinput.js"></script>
    <link href="~/Scripts/Uploader/fileinput.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script>
        var itemHub = $.connection.ItemHub;
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $.connection.hub.start().done(function() {

           //do any thing

        });
         $("#fileinput").fileinput({
             allowedFileExtensions: ["jpg", "png", "gif", "jpeg"],
             maxImageWidth: 700,
             maxImageHeight: 700,
             resizePreference: 'height',
             maxFileCount: 1,
             resizeImage: true
         });


         $("#fileinput").on('fileloaded', function (event, file, previewId, index, reader) {


             var readers = new FileReader();
             readers.onloadend = function () {
                 $(".file-preview-image").attr('src', readers.result);
             }
             readers.readAsDataURL(file);
         });




        $('#btnSave').click(function() {
            var imagesJson = $('.file-preview-image').map(function () {
                var $this = $(this);
                return {
                    image: $this.attr('src'),
                    filename: $this.attr('data-filename')
                };
            }).toArray();

            itemHub.server.getByteArray(imagesJson);
        });
    });

    </script>
    }
```

Hub class code

```
    [HubName("ItemHub")]
    public class ItemHub : Hub
    {
          public void GetByteArray(IEnumerable<ImageData> images)
          {
             foreach (var item in images ?? Enumerable.Empty<ImageData>())
             {
                var tokens = item.Image.Split(',');
                if (tokens.Length > 1)
                {
                   byte[] buffer = Convert.FromBase64String(tokens[1]);

                }
              }
          }
    }

    public class ImageData
    {
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string Filename { get; set; }
        public string Image { get; set; }
    }
```