# How to Send File to SignalR hub From websocket-sharp Client?

Tags: c#, xamarin, signalr, websocket-sharp

We are using the websocket-sharp in one of our applications which establishes a websocket connection with our SignalR Hub on the server, we are able to send the text messages and receive the response for the same but unable to post a `byte[]`.

Code for sending text to server is this:

```
public void TestGroupData(string groupname)
{
    DataCarrier dataCarrier = new DataCarrier()
    {
        H = "BILHub",
        M = "GetAllGroupsFor",
        A = new string[] { groupname }
    };
    string wsPacket = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(payLoad);
    this._ws.Send(wsPacket);
    //this.MakeServerCall(dataCarrier);
}
```

When we try to send `byte[]` using the below code, its not going through:

```
public void TestFileData()
{
    try
    {
        // Read the file data
        Console.WriteLine("Started reading file");
        string fileName = @"C:\Saurabh\Data\Song.mp3";
        byte[] file = File.ReadAllBytes(fileName);
        DataCarrier dataCarrier = new DataCarrier()
        {
            H = "BILHub",
            M = "SendFile",
            A = new object[] { file }
        };
        string wsPacket = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dataCarrier);
        this._ws.SendAsync(file , OnSendComplete);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex);
        //throw;
    }
}
```

Any help with this? How can I set my hub name in `_ws.sendAsync()`?

Comment: As suggested by @bsoulier , Use signalR to send real time message example *your mp3 is ready for download and once you receive the message download mp3 from the api*

Comment: I´m curious. Why would you use websocket-sharp rather than SignalR client?

Comment: Our client apps are developed using xamarin and the signalr client doesn't supports websocket o the mono platfrom, that made us to use websocket-sharb. @xleon

Comment: Xamarin supports SSE as transport protocol and it works really well. Unless you need websockets for an specific reason. I´m also curious about how you connect to signalr with WS. I thought that wasn´t possible. Any link to docs?

Comment: SSE with AJAX for bi-directional communication will have much higher round-trip latency and higher client->server bandwidth than using a WebSocket connection.

I based my logic based on the details provided here: https://github.com/sta/websocket-sharp @xleon

Comment: you can use [SignalGo][1] project, that is open source project and have more than features:
  [1]: https://github.com/SignalGo/server-net

Comment: @SaurabhSashank Can I ask whether you solved this and how? Did you manage to set it up so your SignalR server receives `bytes[]` or a stream?

Answer (score 8):

[Sending big files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9999950/asp-net-mvc-upload-a-file-with-signalr) is not really what SignalR is meant for.

SignalR is good for **real-time messaging** purposes between server & clients, for a rather small sized messages (as messahe size has a [real impact on performance](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/performance/signalr-performance)).

For such a need I would look into ASP.NET Web API, especially by using [chunked upload](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1034347/Upload-large-files-to-MVC-WebAPI-using-partitionin) (splitting file in multiple pieces to avoid connection interruptions)

Comment: It will great if you add more details from the external resource

Comment: I thought the same, but there's too much code on that one, and examples on how to chunk/merge files using ASPNET are easy to Google.

Comment: we already have a solution using webapi and multipart data upload for the big files, SignalR Client doesn't support websockets on xamarin (mono) that is where we are using  [websocket-sharp](https://github.com/sta/websocket-sharp) on our mono clients,  there is a method in websocket-sharp for sending file, `ws.SendAsync (data, completed)` , how can i make use of this method with my hub is what we are looking for.

Comment: Any "Hello Word" kind example for this implementation?

Comment: Here's one article from CodeProject [here](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1034347/Upload-large-files-to-MVC-WebAPI-using-partitionin), but you can find other examples by looking around.